# Vector of unique pointers error, cannot be referenced after initialization

Tags: c++, sfml, unique-ptr

I'm trying to create a matrix of rectangles in SFML and have them look like a floor.  To do that, I want to use a vector of unique pointers. However, there seems to be an error I don't quite understand.

After successfully initializing the vector, it is declared deleted in the very same function. When I do a similar implementation but using `new` or shared pointers, there are no problems.

What is causing this error, and how can I fix it? The place of occurance is visible below:

Code:

```
sf::Texture texture;

texture.loadFromFile("./resources/wood.jpg");

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::Sprite>> floor;
unsigned counter = 0;
float posX = 0.f, posY = 0.f;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    floor.push_back(std::make_unique<sf::Sprite>());
    floor[i]->setTexture(texture);
    floor[i]->setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(1, 1, 100, 100));
    floor[i]->setPosition(sf::Vector2f(posX, posY));
    counter++;
    posX += 100.f;
    if (counter == 10) {
        posY += 100.f;
        posX = 0.f;
        counter = 0;
    }
}

while (window.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event eH;

    for (auto &sprite : floor)
        window.draw(*sprite.get());

    while (window.pollEvent(eH)) {
        if (eH.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
        if (eH.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased && eH.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
            window.close();
        if (eH.type == sf::Event::Resized)
            glViewport(0, 0, eH.size.width, eH.size.height);
    }

    window.display();
    window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
```

Error description:

> 'std::unique_ptr<sf::Sprite,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: _Do not post a "PNG of formatted code"_ please, post your code instead.

Comment: Add a code, not a screenshot of code.

Comment: And copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output as well ([formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) as code).

Comment: Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54971353/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind when I'll ask for something again.

Comment: There are no unique_ptrs in this code.

Comment: You should keep that in mind _this time_ and edit a [MCVE] into your post so that it is useful not just for you but for future visitors also. SenDjasni did say that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yessir, I think it's fine now and I got the answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
for (auto sprite : floor)
```

attempts to copy each `unique_ptr` into `sprite` one by one, and `unique_ptr`s aren't copyable.

Use

```
for (auto &sprite : floor)
```

instead.

Comment: Yeah that's it, the only place I haven't tried to put a modifier char :) Ty

Comment: @2137Pablo If this answers your question, click the green tick on the left to mark your problem as solved.

Answer (score 0):

`sf::Sprite` is lightweight, you don't need to use `std::unique_ptr<sf::Sprite>`, just use `sf::Sprite` directly: `std::vector<sf::Sprite> floor;`

```
std::vector<sf::Sprite> floor;
...
floor.push_back(sf::Sprite());
floor[i].set...
...
for (auto const& sprite : floor)
    window.draw(sprite);
```

Comment: What do you mean? There are no pointers in the shown example.

Comment: That's actually a great way too, had some problems earlier that led me to using pointers so that's why I ended up like that.